# MATLAB plot moving data points in separate subplots simultaneously

Tags: matlab, plot, simultaneous

I wish to visualize the movement of a data point throughout space across a period of time within MATLAB.  However, the way I want my figure to display is such that only a single instant is plotted at any given time.  That was easy, I simply created a for loop to update my 3D plot display for every set of coordinates (x,y,z) in my data. However, I wish to display 4 different viewing angles of this plot at all times.  I am well aware of how to setup subplots within MATLAB, that is not the issue.  My issue is getting all 4 of these subplots to execute simultaneously so that all 4 subplots are always displaying the same point in time.

How to handle this issue?

As requested, my code for a figure with a single plot is shown below:

```
datan = DATA; %data in form of x,y,z,a,b,c by column for row# of time points

tib=zeros(size(datan,1),12);
tib(:,1:3) = datan(:,1:3);
tib_ref=tib(1,1:3);

for i=1:size(datan,1)
tib(i,1:3)=tib(i,1:3)-tib_ref;
end

angle_to_dircos

close all

figure('Name','Directions (Individual Cycles)','NumberTitle','off')

for cc=1:2
    hold off
    for bb=1:10:size(tib,1);
    scatter3(tib(bb,1),tib(bb,2),tib(bb,3),'green','filled'); %z and y axes are flipped in polhemus system
    hold on
       p0 = [tib(bb,1),tib(bb,2),tib(bb,3)]; 
       p1 = [tib(bb,1)+10*tib(bb,4),tib(bb,2)+10*tib(bb,5),tib(bb,3)+10*tib(bb,6)]; 
       p2 = [tib(bb,1)+10*tib(bb,7),tib(bb,2)+10*tib(bb,8),tib(bb,3)+10*tib(bb,9)];
       p3 = [-(tib(bb,1)+100*tib(bb,10)),-(tib(bb,2)+100*tib(bb,11)),-(tib(bb,3)+100*tib(bb,12))];      
       vectarrow(p0,p1,1,0,0)
       hold on
       vectarrow(p0,p2,0,1,0)
       hold on
       vectarrow(p0,p3,0,0,1)
       hold on
    az = 90;
    el = 0;
    view(az, el);
    xlim([-50,50]);
    ylim([-50,50]);
    zlim([-50,50]);
    xlabel('distance from center in X');
    ylabel('distance from center in Y');
    zlabel('distance from center in Z');
    title('XYZ Scatter Plots of Tracker Position');
    hold on
    plot3(0,0,0,'sk','markerfacecolor',[0,0,0]);
       p0 = [0,0,0]; 
       p1 = [10,0,0]; 
       p2 = [0,10,0];
       p3 = [0,0,100];      
       vectarrow(p0,p1,1,0,0)
       hold on
       vectarrow(p0,p2,0,1,0)
       hold on
       vectarrow(p0,p3,1,0,1)
    drawnow;
end
end
```

Comment: Could you share your code for one figure so that we can get a better understanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: I would be happy to.  However, my code is too long for this comments section.  Is there a better way to share code on here?

Comment: You could edit your post maybe?

Comment: Post has been edited to include code.

Comment: I would also like to note that we play the loop twice, so the outter loop initiated by:

"for cc = 1:2;"

is unnecessary to the overall function.

Comment: Please correct me if I understood the problem incorrectly. I guess you are doing the actual plotting work with the vectarrow functions at the beginning. Do you think it would be slow to update them consecutively? I highly doubt the human eye will be able to notice the delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `set` to update the x and y-data of your points, rather than recreating the plot entirely every time, the update will be simultaneous thanks to Matlab waiting for `drawnow`.

Here's an example

```
figure,
subplot(1,2,1),plot(rand(10,1),rand(10,1),'.'),hold on,p1=plot(rand(1),rand(1),'.r')
subplot(1,2,2),plot(rand(10,1),rand(10,1),'.'),hold on,p2=plot(rand(1),rand(1),'.r')

%# read the red coordinates - I should have stored them before plotting :)
x(1) = get(p1,'xdata');y(1)=get(p1,'ydata');x(2)=get(p2,'xdata');y(2)=get(p2,'ydata');

%# animate
for i=1:100,
   delta = randn(1,2)*0.01;
   x=x+delta(1);
   y=y+delta(2);
   set(p1,'xdata',x(1),'ydata',y(1));
   set(p2,'xdata',x(2),'ydata',y(2));
   pause(0.1),
   drawnow, %# I put this in case you take out the pause
end
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas.  While this did not explicitly solve my problem as I have 3D coordinates and there is no 'zdata' plot command for me to call for the 3rd input, your code gave me a new idea for how to approach this.

Comment: @NateB: There is a `zdata` property that you can update similar to `xdata` and `ydata`. Or were you referring to my 2D example?

Comment: There is a zdata?  I have 2010b and it keeps telling me that the zdata parameter does not exist and I could not find it in the documentation.  Oh well, it is not a big deal as I now have a functional code based off of your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: @NateB: `plot3` and `scatter3` have `zdata`. I guess it's your `vectarrow` function that causes problems? Anyway, glad everything works fine!